# How to remove the white space behind header in Blogger?

Tags: html, css, blogger

I've been trying to remove the white space behind my header. FYI, I've set the Header Bakcground to transparent, but certainly the main (body post) background still looks white.

If I change the main background to transparent, which will make the header turns clear, the body post will obviously turn clear as well. But I only want the header to be clear.

I tried the trick from here: http://www.blogdesignsbydani.com/2013/02/how-to-make-your-own-custom-blog.html (Step 5-6) about last year. But I can't apply the same trick with my current blog: http://silvertreasure.blogspot.com.

Can anybody take a look and see what's wrong with my blog this time?

Comment: Like a right-click blocker actually protects anything. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might have to move your `tabs-outer` div outside of the main container to achieve the look you desire. I can only guess that you want something like this because your description is not clear and the right click block on your blog would not allow me to perform edits more than once. See the attached picture to see how if it should look like this.

[image: Header outside the main container.]

You can then proceed to adjust your widths and background-colors to match your needs.

Comment: Yes, this is the look that I wanna obtain. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

If all you're trying to do is move the main content down below the menu, do this:

```
.fauxborder-left {
    margin-top: 20px; /* or whatever */
}
```

You may also need to apply it to `.fauxborder-right`.

Comment: I'm sorry about the right-click blocker. But I've figured it out already. Thanks for your comment :)